# Making sum of numbers in each column and row of an $m$ by $n$ table nonnegative

Tags: algorithms

Real numbers are written in an $m\times n$ table. A move consists of reversing the signs of the numbers in any row or column. Prove that it is possible to make the sum of the numbers along each row/column nonegative after a finite number of moves.

Here is a solution I saw:

Let $S$ denote the sum of all the numbers on the table. If there is no column/row with a negative sum then we are done. Otherwise, take each row/column where the sum is negative and flip the signs of all the numbers there. Now note that there at most $2^{mn}$ distinct configurations of the table. So, as $S$ increases each time we do this, the all rows/columns will have a nonegative sum after a finite number of moves.

Is the above argument valid? Why is it not possible that none of the $2^{mn}$ configurations have a positive sum in all rows/columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct. You show that

- There is always a feasible move as long as you have not reached your goal.
- You will not repeat a state of the table (since $S$ is always increased).
- There can only be a finite number of configurations (since the table has only $2^{mn}$ possible configurations).

In fact, this is already enough. Assume that you do not find a configuration with only positive sums. This implies that you never stop. However, you never repeat a configuration. Thus, you would need infinitely many possible configurations to never reach a configuration with only positive sums.